# Base point free for $g^1_2$ for hyperelliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, line-bundles

Let $C$ be a curve of genus larger than 1. $C$ is called hyperelliptic if it contains a $g_2^1$ linear system, meaning that $D$ is of degree $2$ with $\dim |D|=1$ if $D$ is such a divisor in this linear system. Then the book said that it has to be base point free. I did not get this result. I used Riemann-Roch and showed that $l(K-D)>0$. But I did not see why it is base point free.

Comment: You are starting from a function $f \in \mathcal{L}(Q_1+Q_2)\subset k(C)$ such that $div(f) = P_1+P_2 -Q_1-Q_2 $ ?

Comment: This question is really badly written. Please read it and try to edit so that it makes sense. And tell us what $D$ you're working with.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry for my bad writing. I try to improve it a bit. Here $D$ is a divisor in such a linear system. As I know the degree of the divisor, and I know $l(D)$ as it is same as dimension of the linear system +1, so I apply the Riemann-Roch to it.

Comment: Hint: suppose there is a nonempty base locus. Now remove it. What happens to your $\mathfrak{g}^{1}_2$?

Comment: @SamirCanning I try to argue like this. Let $B$ be a base locus, nonempty. First the degree will not be 2, as $deg(D-B)=0$ which will have dimension of global sections is one, contradiction to $r=1$. if $deg(B)=1$, then there is a meromorphic function with only one pole and no others, then the curve would be of genus 0, which is a contradiction. Is the argument correct? And is there a proof without argument depending on degree?

Answer (score 1):

In general for every divisor $D$ and point $P$ we have that $\dim|D-P|=\dim|D|$ if and only if $P$ is a base point (from Hartshorne IV 3.1). As a result, if $P$ is a base point of the $g^1_2$ then $\dim|g^1_2-P|=\dim|g^1_2|=1$ by definition. But we have $\deg(g^1_2-P)=\deg(g^1_2)-1=2-1=1$, and degree can be equal to dimension only if $g=0$ or $D=0$ (Hartshorne exercice IV 1.5). As here $g\geq1$ we have $g^1_2=P$ which is impossible for degree reason.

Answer (score -3):

Say $D= p_0 + p$, and suppose $p_0$ is a base-point. The linear system is of $g^1_2$ type means we can vary $p$ as we like and still stay in the linear system. But $p_0 + p \sim p_0 + p'$ implies $p \sim p'$ for any $p$ and $p'$. This occurs only for the Riemann sphere, not a hyperelliptic curve.

Comment: Why can we vary $p$ as we like?